# Require.js Backbone loading view issue

Tags: backbone.js, model-view-controller, requirejs

I have a backbone project that I am converting to require.js so I can learn how to use it. My backbone project works fine before converting. I have gone through and converted the project to use require.js, but in doing so the static data I load into my view from my app.js is not visible. Additionally, I am not able to display any new data added from the form on index.html.

Something is inhibiting the view from showing. I keep getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" on line 17 of my app.js file in the console in chrome. Below are my files. I am pretty sure I am missing something here conceptually, and any input to help me understand why I am not getting this to work would be greatly appreciated.

---

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Inventory App</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/less/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="items">
    <form class="item_form" id="addItem" action="#" name="item_form">
      <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
                 <h2>Inventory App</h2>
                 <span class="required_notification">* Denotes Required Field</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="component">Component:</label>
                <input type="text" name="component" id="component"placeholder="Component" required/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="stockQty">Stock Qty:</label>
                <input type="number" name="stockQty" id="stockQty"placeholder="Stock Qty" required/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="reorderQty">Reorder #:</label>
                <input type="number" number="reorderQty" id="reorderQty" placeholder="Reorder #" required/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="qtyPerCrane">Qty per Crane:</label>
                <input type="number" name="qtyPerCrane" id="qtyPerCrane" placeholder="Qty per Crane" required/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="vendorId">Vendor Id:</label>
                <input type="number" name="vendorID" id="vendorID" placeholder="Vendor ID" required/>
            </li>
            <li>
               <button class="submit" id="add" >Add</button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </form>

<!-- Label Html goes here-->
      <table id="inventory-grid">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Component</th>
            <th>Stock Qty</th>
            <th>Qty Per Crane</th>
            <th>Reorder Qty</th>
            <th>Vendor ID</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="inventory-holder"></tbody>
      </table>
  </div>

<!-- render inventory items-->
  <script id="inventoryTemplate" type="text/template">
      <td>  <%= component %>                                </td>
      <td>  <%= stockQty %>                                 </td>
      <td>  <%= qtyPerCrane %>                              </td>
      <td>  <%= reorderQty %>                               </td>
      <td>  <%= vendorID %>                                 </td>
      <td>  <button class="delete">Delete</button>          </td>
 </script>

  <script data-main='js/main' src="js/lib/require.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

### main.js

```
//configure RequireJS 
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery',
        backbone: 'lib/backbone',
        localStorage: 'lib/backbone.localStorage',
        underscore: 'lib/underscore',
        views: 'views',
        models: 'models',
        collections: 'collections'

    }, 

      // Shim declaration
    'shim': {
        'underscore': {
          'exports': '_'
        },
        'backbone': {
          'deps': ['jquery', 'underscore'],
          'exports': 'Backbone'
        }
    }
});

// call app.js to load static data 
define(['app'], function(AppView) {

var AppView = new AppView();

});
```

---

### app.js

```
// load view with data
define (['jquery', 'backbone'], function($,Backbone) {

    var app = app || {};

    $(function() {
        var inventory = [
            { component: 'bottom bracket', stockQty: '22', reorderQty: '15', qtyPerCrane: '13', vendorID: 'Foster Machine' },
            { component: 'bottom bracket', stockQty: '22', reorderQty: '15', qtyPerCrane: '13', vendorID: 'Foster Machine' },
            { component: 'bottom bracket', stockQty: '22', reorderQty: '15', qtyPerCrane: '13', vendorID: 'Foster Machine' },
            { component: 'bottom bracket', stockQty: '22', reorderQty: '15', qtyPerCrane: '13', vendorID: 'Foster Machine' },
            { component: 'bottom bracket', stockQty: '22', reorderQty: '15', qtyPerCrane: '13', vendorID: 'Foster Machine' }
        ];

        console.log('inventory loaded');

       // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR GETS THROWN
        new app.InventoryView( inventory );
    });
});
```

---

### item.js (views)

```
// site/js/views/item.js

define(['jquery', 'backbone'], function($, Backbone) {

    var app = app || {};

    app.ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'tr',
        className: 'itemContainer',
        template: _.template( $( '#inventoryTemplate' ).html() ),

        events: {
        'click .delete': 'deleteItem'
        },

        deleteItem: function() {
            //Delete model
            this.model.destroy();

            //Delete view
            this.remove();
        },

        render: function() {
            //this.el is what we defined in tagName. use $el to get access to jQuery html() function
            this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.attributes ) );

            return this;
        }
    });

});
```

---

### inventory.js (views)

```
// site/js/views/inventory.js

define(['jquery', 'backbone'], function($, Backbone) {

    var app = app || {};

    app.InventoryView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#items',

        initialize: function( initialInventory ) {
            this.collection = new app.Inventory( initialInventory );
            this.listenTo( this.collection, 'add', this.renderItem );
            this.render();
        },
        events:{
        'click #add':'addItem'
        },

        addItem: function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var formData = {};

            $( '#addItem li' ).children( 'input' ).each( function( i, el ) {
                if( $( el ).val() != '' )
                {
                    formData[ el.id ] = $( el ).val();
                }
            });

            this.collection.add( new app.Item( formData ) );
        },

        // render inventory by rendering each book in its collection
        render: function() {
            this.collection.each(function( item ) {
                this.renderItem( item );
            }, this );
        },

        // render an item by creating an ItemView and appending the
        // element it renders to the inventory's element
        renderItem: function( item ) {
            var itemView = new app.ItemView({
                model: item
            });
            this.$el.find('#inventory-holder').append( itemView.render().el );
        }
    });

});
```

---

### item.js (models)

```
// site/js/models/item.js

define(['jquery', 'backbone'], function($, Backbone) {

    var app = app || {};

    app.Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            component: 'no component',
            stockQty: 'no stock qty',
            reorderQty: 'no reorder qty',
            qtyPerCrane: 'qty per crane',
            vendorID: 'vendor ID'
        }
    });

});
```

---

### inventory.js (collections)

```
// site/js/collections/inventory.js

define(['jquery', 'backbone'], function($, Backbone) {

    var app = app || {};

    app.Inventory = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: app.Item
    });

});
```

Comment: What is the line of code doing that the error is pointing to? If you expand the error, do you see the call stack? If you click on the file link to the right of the error, does it take you to where the error is in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you study an example backbone/requirejs application, to get a feeling, i recommend this excellent project: https://github.com/BenjaminAdams/RedditJS/blob/master/public/js/app/App.js.

So the way you define your application is:

```
// app.js
define(["jquery", "backbone"], function($, Backbone) {
  // not exactly this but similar define your app here.  
  // get rid of all of this: `var app = app || {};`
  var App = new Backbone.application();

  // don't forget to return the Backbone App.
  return App;
});
```

define a backbone view:

```
// sampleView.js
define(["App", "backbone", "hbs!template/comment"], function(App, Backbone, commentTmpl) {
  // Use the variable App safely here rather than `var app = app || {};`
  return Backbone.View.extend({});
});
```

define a backbone controller:

```
define(["App", "backbone"], function(App, Backbone) {
  return Backbone.Controller.extend({});
});
```

define a [backbone router](https://github.com/BenjaminAdams/RedditJS/blob/master/public/js/app/router/app-router.js):

```
define(["App", "backbone"], function(App, Backbone) {
  var AppRouter = Backbone.AppRouter.extend({});

  return AppRouter;
});
```

Finally fire up with requirejs `require` function: eg(see [here](https://github.com/BenjaminAdams/RedditJS/blob/master/public/js/app/init/DesktopInit.js))

```
require(["App", "router", "jquery", "backbone"], function(App, AppRouter) {
  App.appRouter = new AppRouter();
  App.start();
});
```

Note that, this is just a dummy example, you should get the idea and apply it to your application backbone way.

Comment: You might want to add that you're pointing at an implementation that uses Marionette. There is no 'application' method on Backbone - that's a Marionette feature.

Comment: @kinakuta I said, this is just a dummy example, and apply it backbone way. Since the question is not about how to implement backbone views etc. it's about how to structure a backbone like project using requirejs.

Comment: Yes, and you should still mention that you're pointing at an example of Marionette, which is a specific framework used to structure applications. Additionally, your code gives an example that explicitly says not to use the var app = app || {} pattern, but instead use a method that doesn't actually exist on Backbone. My suggestions are constructive for your post.

Comment: thanks for your input user3995789 and @kinakuta. I tried to implement the suggestions above but was not successful. I also read through the example you linked to user3995789, but I think i am getting more confused by the addition of Marionette. Do you have any thoughts on how to return the value of 'new app.InventoryView( inventory );' in app.js?

Comment: I said, get rid of all the app's. If you need an Inventoryview you need to require it with requirejs and use the passed argument for view. If you study the example a little hard you will solve your problem. Don't expect a fish here dude.

Comment: Sorry, the inclusion of 'app' was a typo on my part in my last comment. I removed all the instances of 'app=app|| {}' as you suggested and was trying to figure out how to load my view (inventoryView) with the data I declared in app.js without using Marionette. I've been refactoring my test project to the adhere to the outline you posted. Your suggestion to require inventoryView with requirejs and pass it in as an argument makes sense. I'm a newbie with all this, so I've been getting confused easily. I'll keep plugging away until I get this figured out. Thanks for your input.

Comment: off topic, instead of passing `app` around, make you modules return an object and make you application actually modular (e.g each module is self contained)

Answer (score 0):

new app.InventoryView( inventory ); would throw error because it is undefined in app.js.

You need to load the InventoryView.js inside the app.js like

```
   define (['jquery', 'backbone', 'InventoryView'], function($,Backbone,InventoryView) {

        var app = app || {};

        $(function() {
            var inventory = [
                { component: 'bottom bracket',.... },....... Your Code

            ];

            console.log('inventory loaded');
          app.InventoryView = InventoryView( inventory );

    // AND NOW YOU CAN CALL YOUR LINE
              new app.InventoryView();

        });
    });
```

While using RequireJS you must load the file(make sure it returning some value) and take reference of it in the inline function and use it.